# how to onFormSubmit(), two separate google source spreadsheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two google separate forms that submit new client data to two separate spreadsheets. How would I use the onFormSubmit() on two separate spreadsheet sources in one app script editor? thank you all very much :D

if this is getting one sheet how could it implement two or more?
i think i get SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('xyz');
and im a little unsure exactly what an active sheet is or activated I think it is the sheet you're currently on in the spreadsheet the dev app script is being derived from. I might be missing some other basic concepts

```
function onFormSubmit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('New Client Submission Form (Phone)'&&'New Client Submission Form (Emailed)')
  var activeRng = sht.getRange("A2:K2")
  var values = activeRng.getValues()
  var height = values.length
  var width = values[0].length
  var ss_dest = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1wgzUSXFNLFQz6tv42Cp_o94qRPAB9IkZnKP5tGL003o')
  var sht_dest = ss_dest.getSheetByName('Estimate Compiler')
  var destRange = sht_dest.getRange(2,1,height,width)
  destRange.setValues(values)
  }
```

this function does exatly as expected I just don't know how to implement two or more yet

Comment: You can link multiple forms to the same spreadsheet  and multiple tabs.  Using the [onFormSubmit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) `e.range.getSheet()` to determine which linked sheets they were going to and thus which form that they came from.

Comment: So you could tell what form they came from with something like this: `function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var formObj={LinkedSheet1:FormName1,LinkedSheet2:FormName2};
  var form=formObj[e.range.getSheet().getName()];
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function onFormSubmit(e) { 
  var formObj={LinkedSheet1:FormName1,LinkedSheet2:FormName2};//you provide this from a knowledge of the connection between the form and linked sheet 
  var form=formObj[e.range.getSheet().getName()];//this returns the form for each sheet
  switch (form) {
    case 'FormName1':
      //code for FormName1
      break;
    case 'FormName2':
      //code for FormName2
      break;
  }
}
```

[onFormSubmit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: ok i see thats exactly what i needed i think i need to replace LinkedSheet1:FormName1,LinkedSheet2:FormName2 with the actual names am i right?

Comment: Yes.  You need to add the actual names of the forms to the formObj and the switch statement. In order word you need to replace `FormName1 and FormName2` with the actual form names.